# What are the solutions of $\frac{\pi^e}{x-e}+\frac{e^\pi}{x-\pi}+\frac{\pi^\pi+e^e}{x-\pi-e}=0$?

Tags: calculus, quadratics

> Prove that $$\frac{\pi^e}{x-e}+\frac{e^\pi}{x-\pi}+\frac{\pi^\pi+e^e}{x-\pi-e}=0$$ has one real root in$(e,\pi)$ and other in $(\pi,\pi+e)$.

For $x\in (-\infty,e)$ the equation will be always be negative and for $x\in (\pi+e,\infty)$ the equation will be always positive so roots must lie in $(e,\pi+e)$.

Now how to do for specific intervals?

Like, if we could prove equation is negative for x=$e^+$ and positive for $x=\pi^-$,then one real root would lie in this interval.

But how do we do this?

Comment: When reducing to a common denominator, the numerator is a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And how are you proved your assertion: "if we could prove equation is negative for $x > e$ and positive for $x< \pi$ ,then one real root would lie in this interval"? Remember the equation is not defined for all $ x \in \mathbb R$ since it is we cannot have $x = \pi$, $x = e$ or $x = e + \pi$.

Comment: In general, if $k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n$ are positive real numbers, and $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ are real numbers such that $$a_1<a_2<\ldots<\ldots <a_n\,,$$ then the equation $$\frac{k_1}{x-a_1}+\frac{k_2}{x-a_2}+\ldots+\frac{k_n}{x-a_n}=0$$ has exactly $n-1$ solutions $x\in\mathbb{C}$.  All solutions $t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_{n-1}$ are real numbers.  If $$t_1\leq t_2\leq \ldots\leq t_{n-1}\,,$$ then
$$a_1<t_1<a_2<t_2<a_3<\ldots<a_{n-1}<t_{n-1}<t_n\,.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The roots of $$f(x)=\frac{\pi^e}{x-e}+\frac{e^\pi}{x-\pi}+\frac{\pi^\pi+e^e}{x-\pi-e}=0$$
and $$g(x)=\pi^e(x-\pi)(x-\pi-e)+e^{\pi}(x-e)(x-e-\pi)+(\pi^\pi+e^e)(x-e)(x-\pi)=0$$
would coincide
Note that $$g(e)=\pi^{1+e}(\pi-e)>0,~~ g(\pi)=e^{\pi+1}(\pi-e)<0,~~ g(e+\pi)=e\pi(\pi^\pi+e^e)>0$$ This proves that the quadratic $g(x)$ has one real root in $(e,\pi)$ and other one in $(\pi, \pi+)e.$ So will be the case for $f(x)=0.$